# Async calls referencing Devices are not completing

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a Windows Store App which will access the device's microphone. However, when I attempt to work with the media devices, execution gets lost in the await somewhere. So far, I've noticed this on the following three scenarios:

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.AudioCapture); // never returns


var inputDeviceId = MediaDevice.GetDefaultAudioCaptureId(AudioDeviceRole.Communications);
var device = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(inputDeviceId); // never returns


var mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio,
    AudioProcessing = AudioProcessing.Default,
    MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Other,
    AudioDeviceId = inputDeviceId,
    VideoDeviceId = "",
 };
 try
 {
     await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings); // never returns
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     throw new Exception("Microphone is not available.", ex);
 }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC and developing on a Surface Pro 2. I have tried debugging in Local Machine and Simulator modes but both with the same results. I do have the Microphone capability selected in the App's manifest. I expect the OS should be prompting me for access to the microphone device but I am not presented with that dialog.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that further up your call stack, you are blocking the UI thread by calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`. This will [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

The reason this deadlocks is because `await` captures a "context" (in this case, the UI context) and will use that to resume its `async` method. However, if the UI thread is blocked, then the `async` method cannot continue.

Comment: You're right! I was calling my async method as `MyMethodAsync().Wait()`. _"This is a problem that is brought up repeatedly on the forums and Stack Overflow. I think it's the most-asked question by async newcomers once they've learned the basics._" -Nailed it!

Comment: ...that is to say, I was calling Wait() in a method which was not async ;) I was not aware of the context implications of async/await. Thanks for the blog posts!